# Using arrays in Firebase authz rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a custom FB token that decrypts to something like the following

```
{
    "uid" : "fred"
    "d" : {
        "roles" : [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to lock down my data so that only users with `foo` role can access the data. How do I write a Firebase authz rule to do that? I tried something like this, but it wouldn't compile. I don't think it likes the indexOf() method.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.role != null && auth.role.indexOf('foo') > 0",
        ".write": false,
}
```

gives me the following error:

> Type error: Function call on target that is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my JSON to be formatted like this:

```
{
    "uid" : "fred"
    "d" : {
        "roles" : {
            "foo" : true,
            "bar" : true
        }
    }
}
```

And my authz rule to

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.role != null && auth.role['foo'] == true",
        ".write": false,
}
```